# Callback individual image when each image successfully loaded?

Tags: jquery, image, animation, fade

How to detect if an image is loaded beforehand, then perform a callback animation to fade in the image?

I've 10 images scatter all over my website, I've simplified the html below for example:

```
<header>
    <img src="headerImage.jpg" />
</header>
<div class="content">
    <img src="contentImage.jpg" />
</div>
<footer>
    <img src="mylogo.jpg" />
    copyright 2014 mywebsite.com
</footer>
```

In my css I have set all my images opacity to 0 by default:

```
<style>
    img{opacity:0;}
</style>
```

To fade in the images I used:

```
$("img").animate({'opacity':1 },600);
```

Now the problem I'm facing is all images will fade in regardless of whether it is loaded or not in one go. Is there a way to detect **individual** image after it is **loaded**, then only **fade in/trigger the animation callback**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**load event**](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded.

*Code*

```
$('img').load(function(){
    $(this).animate({'opacity':1 },600);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/bfe5K/1/)

> As soon as the image has been loaded, the handler is called.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I tried it out and works fine, but noticed another problem. Somehow certain images don't load and remain opacity=0. I notice those images that do not load are hosted from another server.....